# How to balance the classes with the code of Inception-v3 model?

Tags: tensorflow

### models/inception/inception/image_processing.py

I am a beginner in tersorflow. I am using the implementation of Inception-V3 expressed in TF-Slim, training from scratch with a different dataset. I am trying to solve a problem of 5 classes, and the dataset is completely unbalanced. The first class has more data than the total of the other 4 classes. The loss doesn't fall, and as expected, unfortunately all the images are classified as "1".

I am understanding partially how the tensorflow works, but am facing a problem now and don't know how to solve it. How could we construct batches balanced by classes? The most simple way, I believe, would be to address the class balancing in parallel with the data augmentation. That consist of applying oversampling, duplicating the images of the less favored classes (before distorting them) in order to balance with the most populated. But I don't want to do this manually (that would occupy a large extra space in disk), and I prefer to do dynamically.

For brevity, suppose we have 2000 images, 500 images and 100 images for classes 1, 2, and 3 respectively. To balance the classes, we would repeat each data from the class 2 with (3 copies) and class 3 (19 copies). The copies (or repetitions) would be done before applying image distortions.

The data is in the native TFRecord format. Could someone help me solve this problem?

Code: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/image_processing.py

---

UPDATE:

Thanks to other two similar threads ([Online oversampling in Tensorflow input pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38484075/online-oversampling-in-tensorflow-input-pipeline) and [How to duplicate input tensors conditional on a tensor attribute ("oversampling") in a Tensorflow queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40910834/how-to-duplicate-input-tensors-conditional-on-a-tensor-attribute-oversampling)), I have a solution to the problem.

Like @citrusvanilla, I've tried to use `tf.case()`, but it didn't work. `tf.cond()` was enough. In my case, I'd need to apply some random perturbations to each version of the image. I don't know if that is most suitable option, but I'm using `tf.map_fn()` to solve this.

```
`# Example for three classes (class 0 is not used)

def oversample_by_cond(images, label):
   # Oversampling factors per class
   OVERSAMPLE_FACTOR = [1, 1, 4]

   # Set up the predicates
   pred0 = tf.reshape(tf.equal(label, tf.convert_to_tensor([0])), [])
   pred1 = tf.reshape(tf.equal(label, tf.convert_to_tensor([1])), [])
   pred2 = tf.reshape(tf.equal(label, tf.convert_to_tensor([2])), [])

   # Callables functions
   def f0(): return tf.concat([images]*OVERSAMPLE_FACTOR[0], 0), tf.concat([label]*OVERSAMPLE_FACTOR[0], 0)
   def f1(): return tf.concat([images]*OVERSAMPLE_FACTOR[1], 0), tf.concat([label]*OVERSAMPLE_FACTOR[1], 0)
   def f2(): return tf.concat([images]*OVERSAMPLE_FACTOR[2], 0), tf.concat([label]*OVERSAMPLE_FACTOR[2], 0)

   # Exclusive conditionals (one for each class)
   [images, label] = tf.cond(pred0, f0, lambda: [images,label])
   [images, label] = tf.cond(pred1, f1, lambda: [images,label])
   [images, label] = tf.cond(pred2, f2, lambda: [images,label])

   return [images, label]

images = tf.expand_dims(image_decoded, 0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

if train:
    # Oversample the train set in order to balance the classes
    [images, labels] = oversample_by_cond(images, label_index)

    # Distort all the concatenated version of the training image
    thread_id = itertools.cycle(range(num_preprocess_threads))
    images = tf.map_fn(lambda img: image_preprocessing(img, bbox, train,
        next(thread_id), summariesFlag=False), images)
    images_and_labels = [images, labels]

else:
    # validation/test set
    image = image_preprocessing(image_decoded, bbox, train, thread_id)
    images_and_labels = [tf.expand_dims(image, 0), label_index]`
```

Answer (score 0):

As an initial approach, have you tried just reducing the number of examples in your large class so that it has the same small number as the others? this will at least give you a rough idea of how feasible training with that size is.

I would also strongly consider using transfer learning if you do only have a small dataset, so that you can build on a network that's been trained on another problem with a large training set, and just fine-tune it. There's some information on doing that in slim here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/slim/README.md#reusing-the-vgg16-network-defined-in-tf-slim-on-a-different-task-ie-pascal-voc

You can also check out the TensorFlow for Poets tutorial:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html#0

Comment: Thank you, @Pete,  for your recommendations. The difference between the number of images for each class is too large. Just to get an idea, I would need to oversample one of the classes with a factor of 35 to balance with the most populated class. And the dataset is not so large. Then, reducing the number of examples would not be viable (I know that is just to get an idea). I have used fine-tuning in some experiments, but again, this would not solve class imbalance. I found a solution two/three days after make the question. It's working properly.